# Android ConstraintLayout Simple Example Dilemma: Need for Invisible Bounding Box

Tags: android

This is a simple ConstraintLayout that works as intended: two rows with a label and a value aligned on baseline:

[image]

The problem is the layout depends on the relative sizes of the left and right views. If the sizes are swapped the layout is bad:

[image]

The views on which the baseline and top constraints must be reversed.

A better way would allow a baseline constraint to be symmetrical (i.e. not depend on which member it was placed), and to allow multiple topOf constraints to resolve by topmost top after the baseline constraint was satisfied. The effective top is the top of the bounding box after the views are constrained relative to each other by the baseline constraint.

Is there some aspect of ConstraintLayout that can already do this? If not, is this a reasonable suggestion for improvement?

Comment: You try Barriers?

Comment: I looked at Group and Guideline, but Barrier looks like the one. Thanks! Will check it out...

Comment: Barriers don't seem to help with baseline constrained text. The problem is a a barrier cannot be constrained to something to establish the position of the members of the barrier. For example, the top barrier of the 2nd row connected to the bottom barrier of the first row, and the top barrier of the first row connected to the parent.

Comment: I added an example in an answer

Comment: Did my example not work for you?

Comment: It is not that you can't make it work, but rather that the constraint attributes need to be consistent with the size of the view being constrained. So in your example below if the first text is bigger than the second your layout is wrong. The baseline constraints must be applied in reverse.

Comment: My suggestion is if view are constraint relative to other views, but not to the parent view on at least one axis then a barrier unambiguously could be used to constraint the barrier to the parent, or another barrier, or even a child view. If the latter two are constrained on the axis to the parent, the degree of freedom is then lost. Also you have 2 vertical axis constraints on the first view, an the baseline constraint wins, but is this formally permitted (i.e. not break in the next versions)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="TextView1"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView, textView2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="TextView3"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:text="TextView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```